# Basic behavior of protractor with functions outside of the it block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I tried to source one function out in protractor so that it is outside of the it-block. Before the "outsourcing" it worked fine.

That's my Code:

```
it('should delete a private linked clone', function () {
            let countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore;
            let countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter;
            vmPortal.navigationbar.navPersonalClients.click();

            countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore = countPrivateLinkedClones();

            console.log(Count of private linked Clones before elimination: ', countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore);

            vmPortal.personalClients.firstLinkedCloneRow.element(by.css('button.btn-danger')).click();
            vmPortal.modalCreateMachine.btnModalDeleteMachine.click();

            countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter = countPrivateLinkedClones();
            console.log('Count of private linked Clones after elimination: ', countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore);
            expect(countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter === countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore - 1);
 });
```

so my function is **countPrivateLinkedClones()**

```
    countPrivateLinkedClones =  function () {
                let countPLC;

                vmPortal.personalClients.linkedCloneList.count().then(function (count) {
                    console.log("Count of private linked Clones:", count)
                    countPLC = count;
                });
                return countPLC;
}
```

If I run this the result is:

.Count of private linked Clones before elimination:  undefined

Count of private linked Clones after elimination:  undefined

Count of private linked Clones: 3

Count of private linked Clones: 2

**What is the reason for this behavior?**

**How to fix it, so that the function is not executed at the end instead of where i want to have it executed?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though `vmPortal.personalClients.linkedCloneList.count()` is an asynchronous function returning a `Promise`. So the callback function passed to `.then()` is called when the `Promise` resolves which is guaranteed not to happen until the rest of your code completes.

In particular that means you cannot return `countPLC` from `countPrivateLinkedClones` because the value is guaranteed to not be set at that point. Instead you must return a `Promise` and the calling test can then get at the value when the `Promise` resolves.

In turn that means the test has to be written as an asynchronous test.

So make the first function return a `Promise` that will resolve to the `count` value when it is available:

```
function countPrivateLinkedClones () {
    let countPLC;

    return vmPortal.personalClients.linkedCloneList.count().then(function (count) {
        console.log("Count of private linked Clones:", count)
        return count;
     });
}
```

Make the test asynchronous by using the `done` parameter passed to the test function and use the Promises:

```
it('should delete a private linked clone', function (done) {
    let countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore;
    let countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter;
    vmPortal.navigationbar.navPersonalClients.click();

    countPrivateLinkedClones().then(count => {
        countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore = count;
        console.log('Count of private linked Clones before elimination: ', countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore);

        vmPortal.personalClients.firstLinkedCloneRow.element(by.css('button.btn-danger')).click();
        vmPortal.modalCreateMachine.btnModalDeleteMachine.click();

        return countPrivateLinkedClones();
    }).then(count => {
        couuntPrivateLinkedClonesAfter = count;
        console.log('Count of private linked Clones after elimination: ', countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore);
        expect(countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter === countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore - 1);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The countPrivateLinkedClones from what I can see is an async function, is either an ajax request, that means that will execute when the ajax is back, or is calling to a promise that means it will execute when the promise is resolved... at the end of the function..
Since you are using ES6 I suggest to use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), are functions that generates a sequence of values, but not all at once, as a standard function would, but on a per request basis.

```
function* generatorPrivateLink() {
            let countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore;
            let countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter;
            vmPortal.navigationbar.navPersonalClients.click();

            countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore = yield countPrivateLinkedClones();

            console.log(Count of private linked Clones before elimination: ', countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore);

            vmPortal.personalClients.firstLinkedCloneRow.element(by.css('button.btn-danger')).click();
            vmPortal.modalCreateMachine.btnModalDeleteMachine.click();

            countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter = yield ountPrivateLinkedClones();
            console.log('Count of private linked Clones after elimination: ', countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore);
            expect(countPrivateLinkedClonesAfter === countPrivateLinkedClonesBefore - 1);
 }
```

you can define a new generator function and each time you call countPrivateLinkClones(), you can use the 'yield' keyword..